# Gtkada vertical separator not displayed

Tags: gtk, ada

I'm working on an HMI in Ada with Gtkada and I want to create a vertical separator (Gtk_Vseparator) but it is not being displayed. I placed it in an alignment, when I add a button in the alignment it appears but when I add the separator it doesn't and I have no idea why.

Here is my code:

```
   Win                  : Gtk_Window;
   Notebook             : Gtk_Notebook;
   Notebook_Label       : Gtk_Label;
   Box_0                : Gtk_Vbox;
   Alignment_1          : Gtk_Alignment;
   Generate_Button      : Gtk_Button;
   Box_1                : Gtk_Hbox;
   Box_2_Add            : Gtk_Vbox;
   Alignment_2          : Gtk_Alignment;
   Add_Delete_Separator : Gtk_Vseparator;
   Box_2_Delete         : Gtk_Vbox;

   Init;
   Gtk_New (Win, Window_Toplevel);
   Gtk_New (Notebook);
   Gtk_New (Notebook_Label, "Generation");
   Gtk_New_Vbox (Box_0, Homogeneous => False, Spacing => 20);
   Gtk_New (Alignment_1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
   Gtk_New (Generate_Button, "Generate model");
   Gtk_New_Hbox (Box_1, Homogeneous => False);
   Gtk_New_Vbox (Box_2_Add, Homogeneous => False);
   Gtk_New (Alignment_2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
   Gtk_New_Vseparator (Add_Delete_Separator);
   Gtk_New_Vbox (Box_2_Delete, Homogeneous => False);

   Add_Delete_Separator.Show;
   Alignment_2.Add (Add_Delete_Separator);
   Box_1.Pack_End (Box_2_Add, Expand => True, Fill => True);
   Box_1.Pack_End (Alignment_2, Expand => True, Fill => True);
   Box_1.Pack_End (Box_2_Delete, Expand => True, Fill => True);
   Alignment_1.Add (Generate_Button);
   Box_0.Pack_End (Box_1, Expand => True, Fill => True);
   Box_0.Pack_End (Alignment_1, Expand => False, Fill => True); 

   Notebook.Append_Page (Box_0, Notebook_Label);
   Win.Set_Title ("Generator");
   Win.Set_Default_Size (1200, 800);
   Win.Set_Position (Win_Pos_Center);
   Win.Add (Notebook);
   Win.Show_All;

   Main;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Vseparator` has no minimum desired height. Therefore, you need to tell the alignment where you place it in that it should use all available vertical space:

```
Gtk_New (Alignment_2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0);
```

By the way, please post your code as [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Stripping away `begin` etc. does not make the code more readable.